# Boost iterator_facade and forward declarations

Tags: c++, crtp, boost-iterators

I want to create a custom container that supports iterators. It looks like this:

```
class SomeContainer {
    ...
public:
    typedef SomeIterator iterator;
    iterator begin() { ... }
    iterator end() { ... }
};
```

Then I create an iterator for this:

```
class SomeIterator: public boost::iterator_facade<
         SomeIterator, 
         SomeType,
         boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag> {
    ...
}
```

The problem with this is the following. If I declare `SomeContainer` before `SomeiIterator` and forward declare `SomeIterator`, then the compiler complains st the `begin()` and `end()` methods that `SomeIterator` is an incomplete type. However, if I do it the other way, then the problem is the other way around: `SomeContainer` is incomplete.

1. Is it possible to solve this problem while having both classes fully header-only and all methods implicit inline (they mostly contain only a few lines)?
2. If not, is it possible to solve it with factoring out some methods into cpp files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to satisfy your first requirement partially, in that you can define everything in the header except for `begin` and `end` that will need to be declared `inline` and defined outside the `SomeContainer` definition, and after the `SomeIterator` definition (which completes the type). This assumes you keep the current order of definition (`SomeContainer` before `SomeIterator`), which I suggest you keep.

Otherwise, you can certainly ditch `inline` (implicit or otherwise) and define outside the class definitions. By doing so, both types will be complete from those definitions.

Comment: whoops, I mistyped it. The template parameters are SomeIterator and SomeContainer, respectively.